# Can't Get One Complete Background In Frameset

Tags: html, css, frames, frameset

I am trying to get one complete background in a frameset...
I can't seem to do it - when I add < body > the color background I want shows but not the framset.
Is there an easy way to put a complete background of color or color fades first and then have the framset showing with the background colors still there...

I have tried a < div class=propercolor > and no luck - and as related the body tag doesn't work either.  I find online where I can have each frameset specify a color = but when I do that - the fading gets wrecked...

This class is just an example of fading - which works elsewhere...

Any help is appreciated - thx.

```
      .propercolor { 
      background-image: -webkit-gradient(
  linear,
  left top,
  left bottom,
  color-stop(0, white),
  color-stop(1, red)
      );


      <HTML>

      <frameset rows="15%,75%,10%">

        <frame src="pit.cfm" frameborder="0" scrolling="no">

          <frameset cols="60%,40%">
           <FRAME src="schedule.cfm" name="pi" frameborder="0" scrolling="no">
           <FRAME src="banners.cfm" name="banner" frameborder="0" scrolling="no">
          </frameset>

        <frame src="pib.cfm" frameborder="0" scrolling="no">

      </frameset>

      </HTML>
```

Comment: Framesets? It's not the early 90s anymore!

Comment: Sorry had some cold fusion code in and pulled it out - but didn't delete.  Ingo - suggestions? I'm trying to do something short and easy for display purposes.

Comment: Yes: Don't use framesets. And I do mean that. For one, it is outdated, terrible stuff to work with. Secondly, it makes what you want to do much harder (only possible with some odd hacks). Just use `div` elements or, better yet, descriptive HTML5 elements such as `nav` and `main`.

Comment: Will look into thanx... I do need to do different reloads every few minutes as well...

Comment: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/yyrxs/)'s a quick and dirty example. At least it shows what I believe is your question: Separate sections, but one shared background (gradient), right?